# Как прервать обработку большого xml файла php

Tags: xml, php

Привет, первый раз тут)
Ребят подскажите, значит имеется огромный xml файл каталога (прайса) который надо обрабатывать и загружать товары в бд сайта, если я начну одним махом все сразу грузить, то на загрузку 1 товара уходит примерно 1-5 сек. Товаров там около 20 000, итого около 10 часов!

Я просто не могу на такое время запускать скрипт и вешать сайт, моя идея обрабатывать по 5-10 записей, и выключатся.

Использую вот такую обычную схему, обработка через xml_parse:

```
// задаем кодировку

$this->xml_parser = xml_parser_create ( $this->conf['code_xml'] ); 
xml_set_object ( $this->xml_parser, $this ); // обрабатывать будет THIS класс
xml_parser_set_option($this->xml_parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 1);
xml_set_element_handler($this->xml_parser, "startElement", "endElement"); // функции обработки тегов
xml_set_character_data_handler($this->xml_parser, "characterData"); // функции обработки данных



$data = file_get_contents( $file );
if (!xml_parse($this->xml_parser, $data )) {
         $error=xml_error_string(xml_get_error_code($this->xml_parser));
         $line=xml_get_current_line_number($this->xml_parser);
         $this->error(sprintf("XML error: %s at line %d",$error,$line));
}
xml_parser_free($this->xml_parser);
```

ну и там когда я загружу 10 товаров, я в функциях закрывания делаю условие, 
если загружено 5 то `return` во всех функциях.

Но опять же он все равно идет по всему дереву xml файла, я понимаю что конечно быстро но все же, может быть есть какой-то метод прервать обработку, например как прерывание цикла: `break;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А может Вам проще вносить данные из XML-файла в локальную БД, а уже из неё перебрасывать данные "порциями" на сервер? Так наверное будет гораздо проще: можете подключаться - отключаться сколько Вам угодно, выбирать необходимое кол-во записей для отправки в отдельной сессии. Попробуйте, PHP (и другие языки) + SQL позволят это реализовать.

Comment: Вот и мне кажется что одним php тут не обойтись.

Comment: хм ладно :( прям слезы наворачиваются, прям нельзя никак чтоль :( и сгенерировать ошибку xml какую нить как нить?
эх мож еще есть способы обработки xml файла кроме этого метода?

Comment: Кстати, а почему XML-файл такой большой? Это сразу вся база? Есть возможность разбивки данных по категориям товара?

Answer (score 0):

Однозначно будет идти по всему дереву.

1. документ читается сверху вниз.
2. если даже скрипт будет искать 2897 строку, он всеравно начнет сверху.

Точно не скажу как будет работать, но можно попробывать реализовать на Cron php

Comment: спасиб конечно) но блин я итак знаю все это.
мне надо как то прервать файл, я знаю что он читается сверху вниз. как мне прервать это например на 200 строке, остановить обработку всего, не с помощью die как делаю я) а корректно чтобы выполнился код после обработчика еще...